# Make php date dropdown function 'sticky'

Tags: php, forms, function, drop-down-menu

Out of coffee and brain's given up...
...can anyone help to make this form date dropdown function retain selected month on $_POST ['submit'] or isset($missing) in the case of there being an error/missing field etc

```
 function createMonths($id='month_select', $selected=null)
{
    /*** array of months ***/
    $months = array(
            1=>'Jan',
            2=>'Feb',
            3=>'Mar',
            4=>'Apr',
            5=>'May',
            6=>'Jun',
            7=>'Jul',
            8=>'Aug',
            9=>'Sep',
            10=>'Oct',
            11=>'Nov',
            12=>'Dec');

    /*** current month ***/
    $selected = is_null($selected) ? date('m') : $selected;

    $select = '<select name="'.$id.'" id="'.$id.'">'."\n";
    foreach($months as $key=>$mon)
    {
        $select .= '<option value="'.str_pad($key, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).'"';
        $select .= ($key==$selected) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
        $select .= ">$mon</option>\n";


    }
    $select .= '</select>';
    return $select;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the event you have invalid form data, you should check if the **$_POST['month_select']** variable is set and not empty and create your dropdown passing in it's value like so:

```
$selected = (!empty($_POST['month_select'])) ? $_POST['month_select'] : null;
createMonths('month_select', $selected);

function createMonths($id='month_select', $selected = null)
{
    /*** array of months ***/
    $months = array(
            '01'=>'Jan',
            '02'=>'Feb',
            '03'=>'Mar',
            '04'=>'Apr',
            '05'=>'May',
            '06'=>'Jun',
            '07'=>'Jul',
            '08'=>'Aug',
            '09'=>'Sep',
            '10'=>'Oct',
            '11'=>'Nov',
            '12'=>'Dec');

    /*** current month ***/
    $selected = is_null($selected) ? date('n') : $selected;

    $select = '<select name="'.$id.'" id="'.$id.'">'."\n";
    $select .= "<option value=""></option>\n";
    foreach($months as $key => $mon)
    {
        $select .= '<option value="'.$key.'"';
        $select .= ($key == $selected) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
        $select .= ">$mon</option>\n";
    }
    $select .= '</select>';
    return $select;
}
```

I have also taken the liberty of fixing your createMonths() function by the recommendation regarding **date('n')** and changing your array keys to strings as this will avoid having to pad your months.

Comment: as todays month is selected by default variable will never be empty no?

Comment: @brainache - correct, I just added an empty option prior to looping over the months for him.  This isn't necessarily an issue, though, because the selection state on $_POST will only work if the form has been posted.  This is merely useful if you wish to validate that the user has indeed selected an option from the list and not simply passed over *January* in this case.

Comment: To simplify, the above code now starts with an empty selected option.  On submission of the form it will now select the correct option (assuming one was selected) or default to the empty selected option otherwise.

Comment: ok...thanks for your work but where does that make the user selection sticky? 
need 'selected' to be date('n') *cough ;P* until submit after submit 'selected' should be user selection

Comment: It should be sticky.  If no $_POST variable is set, the function will start with *$selected = null* which well then update selected to be *selected = date('n')* which, inside the foreach loop, should match the key and set *selected="selected"*